# Basic SDL2 app compiles with MinGW-w64 but doesn't run

Tags: c, windows, sdl-2, mingw-w64

I'm trying to set up a SDL2 and C development environment on Windows 10 with MinGW-w64.

When trying to run the basic c app with SDL initialization, it compiles without warnings but fails to run afterwards, again without any warnings. Executable just exits.

Here's the source:

```
#include<SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    puts("\nmain...\n");

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        printf("\nInit error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }
    else {
        puts("\nSDL init success...");
    }
}
```

... and the makefile:

```
OBJS = sdl_init.c
EXE_NAME = sdl_init_test
CFLAGS_W = -w -Wl,-subsystem,windows
LFLAGS_W = -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
INCS_W = -IC:\MinGW\devlibs\SDL2-2.0.12\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include
LIBS_W = -LC:\MinGW\devlibs\SDL2-2.0.12\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib

windows_debug:
    gcc $(OBJS) $(INCS_W) $(LIBS_W) $(CFLAGS_W) $(LFLAGS_W) -g -o $(EXE_NAME).exe
```

... and the weird output from gdb:

```
Reading symbols from .\sdl_init_test.exe...
(gdb) list main
12      ../../src/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x402e70: file ../../src/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c, line 17.
```

I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong in the linking phase, but can't pinpoint it exactly.
On Linux, everything compiles, runs and debugs as expected.

---

Here's a corrected makefile, as [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63262022/7854673) which will compile and work fine in Windows console:

```
SRC = sdl_init.c
EXE_NAME = sdl_init_test

CFLAGS_W = -Wall -Wl,-subsystem,console
LFLAGS_W = -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
INCS_W = -IC:\MinGW\devlibs\SDL2-2.0.12\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include
LIBS_W = -LC:\MinGW\devlibs\SDL2-2.0.12\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib


windows_debug:
    gcc $(SRC) $(INCS_W) $(LIBS_W) $(CFLAGS_W) $(LFLAGS_W) -g -o $(EXE_NAME).exe
```

Comment: What happens when you run it, nothing? If yes, how do you run it, from the terminal or from the explorer? If from the terminal, try doing it from the explorer.

Comment: How far does it get in your debugger?

Comment: You have probably not placed all the sdl DLL files next to your executable.

Comment: I was running it from the terminal, now tried it from the explorer - it gives me ```Application Error: The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application.```
Quick search reveals it as a rather generic error message in Windows...

Comment: And also, gdb doesn't get me anywhere really. It just references back to crt0_c.c, no matter what I do.
```(gdb) run
Starting program: **************\sdl_init_test.exe
[New Thread 2332.0x3870]
[New Thread 2332.0x4744]
[New Thread 2332.0x24c8]
[Thread 2332.0x24c8 exited with code 3221225595]
[Thread 2332.0x3870 exited with code 3221225595]
[Thread 2332.0x26ac exited with code 3221225595]
During startup program exited with code 0xc000007b.```

Comment: Apparently, that _7b_ error is dll related (I had a 32bit sdl runtime in path). Now with proper 64bit dll I get no error whatsoever, and gdb output remains more the less the same except now _Inferior process exits normally_...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from startup issue with missing dynamic library, you seem to be mislead (arguably by SDL actually being misleading in that aspect) that your `b main` in gdb sets breakpoint in *your* `main` function. That's not the case as SDL [redefines](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/eb3673a9aca3/include/SDL_main.h#l109) `main` to `SDL_main`, so if you have `#include "SDL2.h"` or something similar and SDL have main wrapper implemented for your operating system - your function gets renamed. Internally `main` (or `wmain`, or `WinMain`, or whatever target system uses as user-defined code entry point) is implemented in `SDL2main` library that you link with, and it calls `SDL_main` (your code).

TL;DR use `b SDL_main` in gdb instead.

Second point is why you don't see output text. That's once again windows specific, basically because you've build "GUI" app, which is different from "console" app, and don't really have its `stdout` associated with console output. Output is still there but you can't see it - but it can be redirected to other program or file, e.g. `your_program.exe | more` or `your_program.exe > stdout.txt`. There are ways to reconnect stdout to console (some `freopen` with `CON` magic, as I recall), or you can just build console program instead with `-Wl,-subsystem,console`.

As a side note, `-w` compiler flag (that could be loosely read as "don't ever warn me about any potential problems with my code as I'm 100% sure it is absolutely perfect and all your warnings are unjustified complaints about my perfect code" (sorry)) is a really really bad idea, with some very rare exceptions. Compilers, especially gcc and clang, are very good at giving warnings in places where it really matter, allowing you to spot mistakes early. You want more warnings (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra`, probably more), not no warnings at all. And while we're at it, `OBJS` in makefile logically should mean object files, not sources (of course you technically can call your variables anything you like, it is just misleading).

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanations!
I'm not used to Windows way of handling output and I really learned a lot from your answer, both on Windows console and how SDL works in it. I basically just did a c/p of those gcc windows options from online tutorials, knowing nothing of their inner workings.

And also, here's me staring at the floor for glancing over ```-w``` as _just-a-shortcut_ for ```-Wall```. Duh.

Comment: thanks for this answer, it helped lead me to an answer for myself with a version of this question but using cmake: do _not_ set the WIN32 flag when using app_executable